# Trouble inserting data into MySQL database via html and php form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I’m having trouble successfully INSERTing information into a database I created.  I tried several different alternatives I found on the internet and I was hoping someone could help. From what I can tell I’m connecting to the database without a problem, the data is just not being submitted into it.  I kept it very simple just for testing purposes to no avail. It’s probably something simple that a more experienced programmer could help out easily.

I’m running a server through A2Hosting that is running
“Server version: 10.2.18-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server”
“Php version: 5.6.30”

Here is the code I have running(for security I’m substituted in info):
I did the “dummy checks” with data base table and field names, username and case of letters too.

config.php:

```
<?php
$host = "server.a2hosting.com";
$userName = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbName = "Database";

// Create database connection
$conn = mysql_connect ($host, $userName, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Html file - index.html:

```
<html><body> <form method="post" action="index.php"> <input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name'> <input type='text’ name='last_name'> <input type=submit value="Submit"> </form>
 </body></html>
```

Php file - index.php

```
 <?  include("config.php"); 
// has the access info for the DB, how to connect

 // create a variable
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];

 $query = "INSERT INTO Contact_Information (HOW_name, address) VALUES
 ('$first_name', '$last_name'); "; mysql_query($query); mysql_close();

 ?>


 <html> <head> <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=form1.php">
 </head> </html>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` library. It has been deprecated for a while and has been removed **completely** from PHP7.

Comment: What's not working, can you share an error message?

Comment: For one `type='text’` < contains a curly quote.

Comment: Your code failed in too many ways. What you have in your db declaration doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score -2):

$query = "INSERT INTO contact_inforamarion(how_name, address) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name');";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Query and result should be like this.

Comment: someone's going to set their last name to `doe'); DROP TABLE contact_information;`